# Twig: Set a variable and reuse it in javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig

Before in Symfony 2.8.7 was doing something like

```
  {% set testVar = "test" %}
    {{ testVar }}
     ....
<script> 
 var test= '{{ testVar }}';
  console.log(test);
</script>
```

However this doesn't seem to work anymore in symfony 2.8.17 it's returning Variable "testVar" does not exist. 
Did something fundamental change in the twig engine? How can I achieve the same effect ?

Comment: Please show a bit more code. What you have posted so far does still work. Furthermore, please also show the full error message.

Comment: can  you put that value in data attribute like data-id="1" in twig and get it by using $(this).attr("data-id") in jquery??

Comment: Hmm my bad seems was trying to set the variable inside a {% block dpskoazell_body %}  ...  <% endblock %> and I was trying to read them in a different  block.  Moved them outside in the global scope and now they are readable.

Comment: Yes, blocks all have their own scope. Using data attributes is more convenient to solve this sort of things though.